# Why does Excel VBA not delete rows?

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I'm trying to delete excess rows from a sheet prior to printing and the following code does not work:

```
  ' Should be done!
  Rows(firstRowTemplate + numHits & ":" & lastRow).Select   'get rid of excess rows
  Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  '
  "next line of code"
```

When I run the code straight through, the rows do not get deleted.  If I stop execution before the Selection.Delete line, then step through it, the lines are not deleted.  However, if I stop execution at "next line of code" and then reset the execution pointer to the Selection.Delete command, it works.  The values in firstRowTemplate, numHits, and lastRow show up correctly.  It's as if there is some latency between the .Select and the .Delete.  Any thoughts?

Excel Office 365 (Version 2311 Build 16.0.17029.20028) 64-bit
Windows 11: Edition Windows 11 Home
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎12/‎8/‎2022
OS build    22621.2861
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22681.1000.0

Comment: And what happens when you do `Rows(firstRowTemplate + numHits & ":" & lastRow).Delete Shift:=xlUp` [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/11683)?

Comment: The most likely cause of this behaviour is that the sheet is not active. You can only delete the Selection of the active sheet. If you add a line to activate the sheet before deleting it should work. But @GSerg's suggestion is much better - avoid using Select.

Comment: There is really no reason to actually Select anything with automation code. Yes, the macro recorder does that because it is recording. Look for substitution code that does not use Select. As @GSerg shows in comment.

Comment: Thank you.  That worked fine. I didn't realize that I don't have to "Select" all the time - I've been doing *waaayyyy* too much of that.

Comment: Worth a read:  [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)